# Camera Orientation on HTC Legend running Froyo

Tags: android, camera

I have written a camera app, but since the 2.2 update I have had orientation problems.  This is a common enough issue if you do a search for it. Essentially the camera parameter command to set rotation doesn't do anything which results in being unable to correct portrait photos being rotated -90 upon save.

What I really want to know is if anyone else has this problem on the HTC Legend? My app is Fishing Snapz and it is published on the market. I am hoping someone could download it on a Legend and see if they have the same problem?

Stephen